# How to locate $O$ if $OA=2OC$?

Tags: geometry, transformation, similitude

If you have a segment $[CA]$ and you want to plot the point $O$ such that $(\vec{OC},\vec{OA})=\frac{\pi}{2}  (2\pi)$, and $OA=2OC$. How can you plot $O$?

From the first condition we know that $O$ lies on a semi circle of diameter $[CA]$, but how can we precise exactly where it is from the second condition?

There is a bit complicated way I figured out but I am searching for an easier way.

My way is to draw a triangle similar to $OAC$ that has $C$ and the midpoint $I$ of $[CA]$ as two of its vertices. ($DI=2IC$)

[image]

Here is the question by the way (part 2-b), I was told that it could be solved using isobarycenter or something like that which I do not know much about

[image]

Comment: Write Pythagoras relationship in triangle ACO: $x^2+(2x)^2=2^1, where you have taken $IA=IC=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of an answer, we can drop a perpendicular from $O$ (assuming we know where it is) to $CA$, let $H$ be the foot of this perpendicular.

The area of $CHO$ + the area of $AHO$ is equal to the area of $COA$, and supposing that $OA=2CO=2$

we get, $\frac{CH.OH}{2} +\frac{AH.OH}{2} =1$

And since $CA=\sqrt{5}$ we get that $OH=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$

Now we are able to calculate $CH=\sqrt{1-(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}) ²}=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$

Now we can plot $H$ and draw a perpendicular to $(CA)$ at $H$ and precise the position of $O$ as the intersection between the semi-circle and this perpendicular.

I still believe that there is an easier way though, so if you can help, it will be great.